# Scheduling publish of a new version of existing page results in 404

Tags: 404-error, scheduled-posts

The best way I can explain this is:

I have an already published page (version 1), which I make edits to and want to schedule the new version (version 2) to be published at a later date.

When I schedule this, the live/public page (version 1) results in a 404 and is no longer accessible until version 2 is published.

Is this a bug in my theme or is this standard with Wordpress?

Comment: hmm, what versions? there are no possibility to have two versions of the same page in different state

Answer (score 1):

WordPress doesn't support such versioning natively.

While there is *revisions* functionality it is exclusively for keeping *history* of the changes. There is always only one instance of actual original post at any time and it can only be in one status at the time.

So either it is published, or draft, or pending. There is no such thing as "published with update pending".